# create and save a webite url's snapshot using PHP and any third party service

Tags: php

I want to capture the website screenshot to be saved in my server and displayed in my application.

Presently we were using some API from http://counter3.goingup.com/thumboo/ using the code below :

```
$result = @file_get_contents("http://counter3.goingup.com/thumboo/image.php?i=20c41926583c26fe2297d7aae847e76c|||".$website_url."|||80x50");
@file_put_contents("asset/screenshot/".$file_name,$result);
```

Sinced last week it was generating and saving screenshots properly , but since this week , it's generating an **invalid image** .

Also , as the error is suppressed , it is saving the file , but it's actually a corrupted file

Please suggest how to achieve this . Is there any other free service that I can use alongwith PHP

Comment: Remove the suppress `@`, it should return some useful error message.

Comment: I have already checked that, but it's not returning any errors .

Comment: `var_dump($result);` ? Or simply use your browser to load the said URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this worked for me :
http://counter2.goingup.com/thumboo/image.php?i=1f899e4e1abf9473ccae69de4f3ec1ca|||www.google.com|||600x550

Comment: This URL is giving the error : Url not found error...off late...what may be the reason for this?